# Magento2 : How to get base require js baseUrl to get static files?

Tags: magento2, javascript

I am creating a custom module which retrieves the image from `Package_Module/images/image.jpg` in my javascript code. **How to get the require js base URL or Static URL**? or **do you have any suggestions on what is the best to get the link of an image asset from javascript level**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get site url inside javascript file?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124497/how-to-get-site-url-inside-javascript-file)

Comment: @BenCrook base URL and require js base URL might not be the same. :)

Comment: If the base URL differs between files that is a problem IMO, the base URL should always be the base URL.

Comment: I've added a method to get the pub/static URL including your vendor, theme and locale. It sounds like that may be what you're after when you say the require JS base URL isn't the same?

Comment: Hi @BenCrook, yes, that was I was after. Should I adjust the description of this question?

Comment: I think wording it as the theme static file URL may make more sense, I understand base URL to be the domain only such as https://example.com.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass it through using `x-magento-init` as Khoa mentioned, or you can use this:

```
require.toUrl('test');
```

Which will output:

```
//localhost:3000/static/frontend/Vendor/theme/en_GB/test
```

Where localhost:3000 is your base URL.

Comment: Perfectly, I didn't know about it +1.

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what I need. I just know. :) Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

1) Using the Js global variable. For example, on the checkout page, we can check:

```
window.checkoutConfig.imageData
```

[image]

See more here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/133732/33057

2) Passing the image to Js variable in your phtml:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-block='minicart']": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getJsLayout() ?>
        },
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/block-loader": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif') ?>"
        }
    }
</script>
```